# Effect of "Delete the driver software for this device" checkbox in Windows' Device Manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, drivers, device-manager

In Windows, when deleting a device from Device Manager, the user is sometimes provided with a checkbox that specifies "Delete the driver software for this device".

Does checking that box ever delete drivers that were included with Windows or with a Windows update?

Is the answer the same for both Windows 7 and Windows 10?

Comment: It deletes the driver that was being used.  If you happen to have multiple versions installed, only the driver that was being used, is removed.

Comment: @Ramhound If, for example, you plug in 3 cell phones in succession by the same manufacturer (and all are the same version and model), Device Manager will generally list all 3 devices (if DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1 and Hidden Devices is selected).  Will deleting one of those 3 devices and checking that checkbox remove the drivers for all three, or just one?

Comment: The fact you are using the same driver for three different devices is relevant information that should be in the question body.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure if it's relevant.  I'm only wondering if that checkbox deletes drivers that were included with Windows (or a Windows update).  I very much respect your knowledge, and if there's some way it's relevant that I'm not seeing, just let me know.